# How to sort elements in a list with numbers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to sort this list:

```
<div id="mainMenu">
    <span>Thing 5</span>
    <span>Thing 4</span>
    <span>Thing 7</span>
    <span>Thing 1</span>
    <span>Thing 5</span>
    <span>Thing 6</span>
    <span>Thing 3</span>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
$('#mainMenu').sort(function(){
    $(this).children().sort();
});
```

I want it sorted in this order:

```
<span>Thing 1</span>
<span>Thing 2</span>
<span>Thing 3</span>
<span>Thing 4</span>
<span>Thing 5</span>
<span>Thing 6</span>
<span>Thing 7</span>
```

Comment: you are not sorting the elements, you are modifying its content

Comment: @GajusKuizinas but this isn't a ul/ol. I need the last character sorted not the whole wrod

Comment: That's effectively the same issue.

Comment: @user3400321: Why would it matter what the element type is???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$span = $('#mainMenu span').sort(function(a, b) {
    if ($(a).text() < $(b).text()) return -1;
    if ($(a).text() > $(b).text()) return 1;
    return 0;
});
$('#mainMenu').html($span);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnEH2/)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code work perfectly:**

```
var mylist = $('#mainMenu');
var listitems = mylist.children('span').get();

listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
});
$.each(listitems, function(index, item) {
   mylist.append(item); 
});
```

Comment: thanks in my case this works. I cant vote on this